# Java float to double

Tags: java

I am attempting to convert a `Float` to a `double` but when I do the number is changing. I am having trouble understanding why because I thought doubles have higher precision than floats.

[image]

```
Float f = 111111111111f;
double d = f.doubleValue();
float ff = f.floatValue();
```

As seen in the above picture my `Float` is set to `111111111111` then when I get the double value the number becomes `111111110656`

Comment: Don't post pictures of code

Comment: @Michael seeing as the picture shows the values he's talking about, which we wouldn't be able to see if he just posted code, I don't think it's such a problem in this case.

Comment: https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Stultuske You can add that as a comment along side the code. It would take like 30 seconds to transcribe.

Comment: A float can hold 6 to 9 digits as precision. So indeed 1111_1111_1111f == 1111_1111_0656f == 1.1111_1111E11. _One should not believe everything one reads._